# Clang's different stages of processing

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++

Similar to GCC, clang supports stopping at different stages when processing C/C++. For example, passing a `-E` flag causes it to stop after the pre-processor and `-c` stops before linking.

So far, I am aware of,

1. `-E` : pre-processing
2. `-fsyntax-only` : syntax checking
3. `-S` : assembly
4. `-c` : object code

Am I missing any stopping points between those, or is that it?

Comment: I may be proved wrong, but I would doubt in any modern compiler that assembly is actually a stage before object code, rather it's an alternative output. Most compilers can also link (a separate stage even with one object file as `libc` gets linked in) at the command line.

Comment: I was sort of envisioning a pipeline: Pre-processor -> syntax -> assembly -> object -> final executable. I should have probably added that the numbering I included is more logical than actual; how close you are to the final executable was the way I was looking at it.

Comment: That's how `cc` used to work on a PDP-11, however I think modern compilers will write straight to object files in the normal run of things.

Comment: @abligh As far as I am aware clang is the only C/C++ compiler with an integrated assembler. I haven't heard that either GCC or cl.exe have stopped invoking an external assembler, at least. What they do, rather than directly writing an object file, is write the assembly to a temporary file and then invoke an external assembler on it to create the object file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `-S -emit-llvm` to generate LLVM IR assembly files and just `-emit-llvm` for LLVM bitcode object files. These are the language-independent code representations that clang and other LLVM front-ends generate and pass to LLVM to compile into an executable.